# Probability two matching runs of coin tosses

Tags: pr.probability

If you toss a coin $2\ell-1$ times you get a sequence of outcomes, say, $HTHTHTH$ for $\ell = 4$.  I am trying to work out the probability that there are at least two runs (in other words contiguous subsequences of outcomes) of length $\ell$ that are identical. In this case $HTHT$ occurs twice, starting at the first and third positions.

The problem I am having is how to deal with the overlap between runs. Is there a simple (or not so simple) observation that makes this problem solvable?

I worked it out for some small examples.

```
l=2. Prob is 2/8
l=3. Prob is 8/32
l=4. Prob is 28/128
l=5. Prob is 86/512
l=6. Prob is 250/2048
l=7. Prob is 680/8192
l=8. Prob is 1792/32768
l=9. Prob is 4562/131072
l=10.Prob is 11344/524288
l=11.Prob is 27614/2097152
```

The sequence $2,8,28,86,250$ is http://oeis.org/A118047 but after that it diverges.

If it turns out that an exact solution is not feasible, I would be very interested in any large $\ell$ approximations.

---

Is there  a direct argument which tells us that the probabilities in this problem are bounded above by the case where the runs of length $\ell$ are all independent?

Comment: For overlaps of the runs, look for the keyword "autocorrelation polynomials" which are used in enumerations of strings with various substring properties.

Comment: Since all numerators are even, one might divide each by two and check OEIS. This gives http://oeis.org/A049539, which references: C. J. A. Jansen, Investigations on Nonlinear Stream cipher Systems: Construction and Evaluation Methods, Ph.D. Thesis, Delft University of Technology, The Netherlands, (1989), pp. 58-81. The thesis is available for free here: http://repository.tudelft.nl/assets/uuid:7a13b932-d504-4fa0-866c-979daaeb4360/its_jansen_19890418.PDF (See, e.g., column 10, p.60; ii, p. 81.) Related are paths in a DeBruijn graph; but perhaps this is how you came to the problem initially...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inspecting the bound of Bjorn Kjoss-Hanssen's answer with the numerical results in the question, it seems that the upper bound is about twice as large as the true value.  I give a refined upper bound that saves this factor of $2$, and which I expect is close to the correct answer.  Numerically it seems that $\binom{\ell}{2}2^{-\ell-1}$ is very close to the right answer; the upper bound I give gets the (presumably) right coefficient for the $\ell^2$ term but not the $\ell$ term.

Suppose the string of length $2\ell -1$ is given by values $a(n)$ with $1\le n\le 2\ell -1$.
Suppose that such a string of length $2\ell-1$ has two strings of length $r$ that match, where $r\ge \ell$ and is the maximal length of strings that match.  Then there exist $1\le i< j$ such that $a(i)=a(j)$, $a(i+1)=a(j+1)$, $\ldots$, $a(i+r-1)=a(j+r-1)$ (note that this means $j\le 2\ell-r$), and also we have $a(i-1)\neq a(j-1)$ (this condition doesn't exist if $i=1$) and $a(i+r) \neq a(j+r)$ (this condition doesn't exist when $j+r=2\ell$).   If $1<i$ and $j<2\ell-r$ then the probability that this happens is $2^{-r-2}$.  If $i=1$ or $j=2\ell -r$ but not both then this happens with probability $2^{-r-1}$.  Finally if $i=1$ and $j=2\ell-r$ we obtain a probability of $2^{-r}$.

Thus, by the union bound over the possibilities for $i$ and $j$, for a given value of $\ell \le r \le 2\ell -2$, we have a probability of at most 
 $$ 
 2^{-r-2} \binom{2\ell-r-2}{2} + 2^{-r-1} \cdot 2 \cdot (2\ell -r-2) + 2^{-r}.
 $$ 
 Summing this over all $\ell \le r \le 2\ell-2$ gives our upper bound 
 $$ 
 \sum_{r=\ell}^{2\ell-2} 2^{-r} \Big( \frac{1}{4} \binom{2\ell- r-2}{2} + 2\ell -r -1 \Big) = 
 2^{-\ell} \sum_{k=0}^{\ell-2} 2^{-k} \Big(\frac 14 \binom{\ell-k-2}{2} + \ell-k-1\Big). 
 $$ 
 Asymptotically this bound is about 
 $$ 
 \frac{\ell^2}{4} \cdot 2^{-\ell};
 $$
  that is, about half the size of the previous bound. 
 When $\ell =11$ it gives an upper bound of 
 $$ 
 \frac{33280}{2097152},
 $$ 
 which is closer to the true answer of $27614/2097152$ (and the earlier bound would have a numerator of $56320$).

Comment: Is $r$ is a maximal matching length for a specific occurrence, or the maximum length over all matches within the word? Say in HHHHTTT is $r=3$ the only possibility (from HHHH) or is there also $r=2$ (from TTT)? Or does it not matter?

Comment: @BjørnKjos-Hanssen: In your example $r=3$ is the only possibility (from $HHHH$) according to the definition.  That is, $r$ is the maximum length over all matches within the word (and we are interested in this being at least $\ell$).

Comment: Thank you!  This may be as good as one is going to get (although it would of course be nice to get a lower bound too). Just to help me better understand the role that overlaps play in this problem, I have added a small addendum to the question too.

Answer (score 5):

An upper bound is $${\ell\choose 2} 2^{-\ell} $$ which goes to 0.

Indeed, by the union bound an upper bound is $2^{-\ell}$ times the number of positions $i<j$ such that the two matching runs start at positions $i$ and $j$. We have $1\le i<j\le (2\ell-1)-(\ell-1)=\ell$.

Now, even if the two runs overlap, the number of constrained positions is $\ell$. One way to look at this is to apply the following result of Lyndon and Schutzenberger to the case where the first run is $ab$ and the second is $b\hat a$ (so $b$ is the overlap):

> Theorem. Suppose $a$, $b$ and $\hat{a}$ are strings in an arbitrary
>   alphabet with $ab=b\hat{a}$.
>                 If $|a|\le |b|$ then there is a string $c$ and integers $k$ and $\ell$ such that $a=\hat{a}=c^k$ and $b=c^\ell$.
>                 If $|a|\ge |b|$ then there is a string $u$ with $a=bu$ and $\hat{a}=ub$.

The first few values of this bound starting at $\ell=2$, compared with felix's exact values, are
$$
\frac14=\frac28\color{red}=\frac{\color{red}2}{\color{red}8}
$$
$$
\frac38=\frac{12}{32} \color{red}> \frac{\color{red}8}{\color{red}3\color{red}2}
$$
$$\frac38=\frac{48}{128} \color{red}> \frac{\color{red}2\color{red}8}{\color{red}1\color{red}2\color{red}8}$$
$$
\frac{5}{16} = \frac{160}{512} > \frac{\color{red}8\color{red}6}{\color{red}5\color{red}1\color{red}2}
$$
(Edited to add detail and improve the bound.)

Comment: This is a good upper bound for large $\ell$.

Comment: How do you get this upper bound? There is no harm in being explicit.

Comment: @octonots Thanks, I added some detail

Comment: Is it obvious if the correct answer is bounded above or below the probability one would get if all the $\ell$ length runs were independent?

Comment: @AnthonyQuas Can you give any details for why you believe the upper bound is good when $\ell$ is large?

Comment: If $E_{i,j}$ is the event that the length $\ell$ strings starting at $i$ and at $j$ agree, then clearly, $E_{i,j}$ has probability exactly $2^{-\ell}$. We're asking for the probability of $\bigcup E_{i,j}$. The simple upper bound comes from summing the probabilities. This overcounts only when the $E_{i,j}$ intersect. The probability of such intersections is exponentially smaller.

Comment: Following up octonots comment. Numerically the numbers I gave are certainly bounded above by the fully independent case (where you get 1/4, 11/32, 683/2048, 36677/131072 etc.). The upper bound @BjørnKjos-Hanssen gives is also precisely the asymptotics of the fully independent case. Why should the fully independent case be an upper bound for my problem?

Comment: I must be missing something simple but... How does the result of Lyndon and Schutzenberger (which is very interesting, thank you) tell us that the probabilities in my problem are no more than in the independent case?